# How to change identity provider to htpasswd in oc 3.1

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

How can I change identity provider to HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider?. I'm using origin version 3.11. In 3.9 version I would just change the master-config.yaml file, key identityProviders, to something like this:

```
oauthConfig:
alwaysShowProviderSelection: false
assetPublicURL: https://X.Y.Z.W:8443/console/
grantConfig:
method: auto
serviceAccountMethod: prompt
identityProviders:
- challenge: true
login: true
mappingMethod: claim
name: my_htpasswd_provider
provider:
apiVersion: v1
kind: HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider
file: /root/openshift/data-311/openshift-controller-manager/users.htpasswd
```

In version 3.11 this is not working because there is no master directory in openshift. The file master-config.yaml is present in 3 directories: openshift-controller-manager, openshift-apiserver, kube-apiserver. And I don't know which one to change.
Documentation is always referring to "default master config location" which is /etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml .
By "not working" I mean oc continues to use AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider when I change master-config.yaml in openshift-controller-manager (after cluster restart, of course) . When I change master-config.yaml in two other places, or only one of them (openshift-apiserver, kube-apiserver), then cluster won't start. Error is something like

`"cluster health check failed"` or `"API server error: Get https://x.y.z.w:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp x.y.z.w:8443: connect: connection refused () "`

Answer (score 0):

As of OCP 3.10, the master api and controller service have been provided as static pods, so the htpasswd file should be located into "/etc/origin/master", because the pods are restricted to mount some directories, such as "/etc/origin/master". Refer [Notable Technical Changes - Control Plane as Static Pods](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/release_notes/ocp_3_10_release_notes.html#ocp-310-notable-technical-changes) for more details.

Additionally, you can check what directories the master api and controller pods can refer as follows.

e.g.> you can check the mount directories of the master static pods to allow to refer the htpasswd.

```
$ oc describe <master api or master controller pod name>
```